# Storm - Class Cast Exception while using the parameter in next bolt

Tags: java, apache-kafka, classcastexception, apache-storm

```
int flag = Integer.parseInt((String) arg0.getValueByField(Constants.FLAG));
```

Here, In Storm `arg0.getValueByField(String)` returns an object type. In this case, it is an Integer actually. But then to get this value in the next bolt as an Integer, I wrote the above line of code. But it is giving class cast exception. Can you please suggest what is wrong with it (the casting or what?). I even tried this after that:

```
int flag = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getValueByField(Constants.FLAG).toString());
```

But still same exception.

Comment: If it is *actually* an integer, how about casting it to one? If you print `arg0.getValueByField(...).getClass()`, what does it show?

Comment: Can you add the error message of the exception? If the value is of type `Integer` the second line you tried should actually work (even if it is not a good solution to convert and Integer into a String and than parse the String to get the int back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find whatever you are receiving on the tuple, and then change then change the logic to handle it...

```
public void execute(Tuple input) {

    Object obj = input.getValueByField(Constants.FLAG);
    int flag;
    if (obj instanceof Integer){
        //
        flag = (Integer) obj;
    }
    else if (obj instanceof String){
        flag = Integer.parseInt((String) obj);

    }
    else // you are receiving something else that is neither an integer or String
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("other class type : "+obj.getClass()
                                   +"\t toString(): "+obj.toString());
        // your should be able to see this exception on Storm UI

    }

    // do your thing


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value returned by `arg0.getValueByField(Constants.FLAG)` is of type `Integer` you cannot cast it to `String` as you do.

Simple use a cast to `Integer`:

```
int flag = (Integer)arg0.getValueByField(Constants.FLAG);
```